# Flutter: Add list of object to Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array inside Firestore document. The array store a map list.

[Firestore Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UigWh.png)

So, I want to update data at specific index but Firestore doesnt allow index update. So I had to retrieve the whole array and update the data by object then upload the array back to Firestore. However, I keep getting this error, where it said 'Invalid argument: Instance of 'Evaluate..'' The array is in list of Evaluate object.

```
class Evaluate {
  String sb;
  double mk;

  Evaluate({this.sb, this.mk});
}

class EvaluateList {
  List<dynamic> evaluateList = [];

  EvaluateList({this.evaluateList});
}
```

I met dead end, because I dont know how to upload it now since it is in map and I tried everything. I dont really practice map because its new thing to me but had to apply map for this data because it is the only method and now I'm running out of time to try and error. So can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance :)

Here is my Firestore function:

```
    Future getEvData(String sEv, double nEv) async {

    //manage document snapshot
    DocumentSnapshot evSnapshot = await evCollection.document(uid).get();
    var evMap = evSnapshot.data['evaluate'];
    List<Evaluate> dataEv = extractEvaluation(evMap);

    // calculation for new data
    double oldEv;
    int index = 0;
    int evIndex;

    dataEv.forEach((e) {
      if (e.sb == sEv) {
        oldEv = e.mk;
        evIndex = index;
      }
      index++;
    });

    double newEv = (oldEv + nEv) / 2;
    double percentEv = newEv / 5 * 100;
    dataEv[evIndex].mk = percentEv;

    // update to firestore
    return await evCollection.document(uid).updateData({
      "evaluate": dataEv,
    });

  }
```

If you find better way to structure my database and easier way to queries you may suggest because I'm still learning..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to ignore the model class `Evaluate` here cause it's redundant.
So `dataEv` is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. You first need to remove the exact element from the list.
Using `removeAt`

```dart
dataEv.dataEv.removeAt(index);
```

or using `removeWhere` when the 'mk is 30

```dart
dataEv.removeWhere((item) => item['mk'] == 30);
```

and when the 'sb' is 'chemistry'

```dart
dataEv.removeWhere((item) => item['sb'] == 'chemistry');
```

Then you have to add a new element to the list. For example, if you wanna update 'mk' of 'sb' chemistry from 30 to 50. You do like this.

```dart
dataEv.add({'mk': 50, 'sb': 'chemistry'});
```

if you want to update the 'sb' then you change the 'sb' value like this

```dart
dataEv.add({'mk': 30, 'sb': 'physics'});
```

However, if you wanna update the element at the same index then you have to first store the removed element index using `indexOf` or `indexWhere` then use this index to update the list using `insert`. But I think you don't need to do it. Since you can easily `sort` the list.

finally, update `dataEv` to firestore.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm very grateful for you spending your time to look at my code. I got error on the removeWhere to as my list is fix-length. However, you idea to delete first and then add new data really helpful because I can do that. 

So instead, I remove the the specific map from the array using arrayRemove. Instead of update the whole array, I add the new updated data that I deleted before.

Again, thank youu :)

Comment: This is offtopic but I think it's a good practice to name your variable human readable to remove confusion. Instead of mk, sb, Ev name then like marks, subject, evaluate.
What kinda error you get when you use `removeWhere`? It doesn't matter if it's fixed.

Comment: haha ya I would. The variables werent finalised yet and it become my habit to test the code with small data also mean with simple variable so it be easy to detect error and make changes. But thanks for the advice :)